# Creating simpler fluent interface

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public interface IBehaviour
{
    event EventHandler Completed;
    void Execute();
}

public interface IBehaviourA : IBehaviour
{
    // Some specific stuff here
    object A { get; set; }
}

public interface IBehaviourB : IBehaviour
{
    // Some specific stuff here
    object B {get;set;}
}

public interface IBehaviourQueue
{
    void Run();
    BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour> AddBehaviour<T>() where T : IBehaviour;
}

public class BehaviourQueue : Queue<BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour>>,  IBehaviourQueue
{
    private IBehaviourFactory factory;
    public BehaviourQueue(IBehaviourFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour> AddBehaviour<T>() where T:IBehaviour
    {
        T behaviour = factory.GetNew<T>();
        var queueItem = new BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour>(behaviour);
        Enqueue(queueItem); 
        return queueItem;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        //Run each queue item
    }
}

public class BehaviourQueueItem<T>
{
    public IBehaviour behaviour;

    public BehaviourQueueItem(IBehaviour behaviour)
    {
        this.behaviour = behaviour;
    }

    public void WhenComplete(Func<T, bool> action) 
    {
        CompletedAction = action;
    }

    public BehaviourQueueItem<T> ConfigureFor<Z>(Action<Z> dow) where Z : IBehaviour
    {
        dow((Z)behaviour);
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is how it is used:

```
var q =new BehaviourQueue(new BehaviourFactory()); // Queue here is IBehaviour
q.AddBehaviour<IBehaviourA>()
 .ConfigureFor<IBehaviourA>(x => x.A = "someValueA")
 .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(((IBehaviourA)x).A));

q.AddBehaviour<IBehaviourB >()
 .ConfigureFor<IBehaviourB >(x => x.B = "someValueB")
 .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(((IBehaviourB)x).B));
```

What I don't really like is that I have to specify which type of `IBehaviour` I am referring to every time. I would like to be able to write:

```
var q =new BehaviourQueue(new BehaviourFactory()); // Queue here is IBehaviour
q.AddBehaviour<IBehaviourA>()
 .Configure(x => x.A = "someValueA")
 .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(x.A));

q.AddBehaviour<IBehaviourB>()
 .Configure(x => x.B = "someValueB")
 .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(x.B));
```

I know that I have to modify this part:

```
public BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour> AddBehaviour<T>() where T:IBehaviour
{
    T behaviour = factory.GetNew<T>();
    var queueItem = new BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour>(behaviour);
    Enqueue(queueItem);
    return queueItem;
}
```

to something like

```
public BehaviourQueueItem<T> AddBehaviour<T>() where T:IBehaviour
{
    T behaviour = factory.GetNew<T>();
    var queueItem = new BehaviourQueueItem<T>(behaviour);
    Enqueue(queueItem); // It won't let me know do it because of Covariance/Contravariance thingy
    return queueItem;
}
```

Do you have any idea what I should write to be able to create a base typed list and add specific items and configuring it fluently?

Keep in mind that I should be able to add any type of `IBehaviour` to `BehaviourQueue` so the queue can't be a derived type.

Comment: You will perhaps be interested in how other projects try to handle that, I found that one: http://flit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround would be to declare the `BehaviourQueue` class as being `Queue<object>` instead of `Queue<BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour>>`.

This will allow you to define the `AddBehaviour<T>()` method the way you want:

```
public BehaviourQueueItem<T> AddBehaviour<T>() where T : IBehaviour
{
    T behaviour = factory.GetNew<T>();
    var queueItem = new BehaviourQueueItem<T>(behaviour);
    Enqueue(queueItem); // no problem here now...
    return queueItem;
}
```

Furthermore, you'll be able to change the `ConfigureFor` method to:

```
public BehaviourQueueItem<T> Configure(Action<T> dow)
{
    dow((T)behaviour);
    return this;
}
```

and now the configuration looks like this:

```
q.AddBehaviour<IBehaviourA>()
    .Configure(x => x.A = "someValueA")
    .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(x.A));

q.AddBehaviour<IBehaviourB>()
    .Configure(x => x.B = "someValueB")
    .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(x.B));
```

The only problem that remains is the dirty `Queue<object>` thing, meaning that the `Dequeue`d objects will need to be cast back to `BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour>`.

It's up to you to decide whether that's an acceptable compromise.

However, looking at the code I see that the actual Queue implementation is not meant to be used by the class's clients. Clients don't call `Enqueue` directly, but `AddBehaviour` (which uses `Enqueue` internally). Similarly, I could male the assumption that `Dequeue` is only called by the `Run()` method, when it processes the items. If this is the case, the `BehaviourQueue` class may not even expose the `Queue` interface; it could instead just have a `Queue<object>` field that does the queue job and only expose the `AddBehaviour` and `Run` public methods.

Comment: After applying the changes I had problem casting IBehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour> back to  IBehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviourA>. Making T covariant on IBehaviourQueueItem interface made it work.

public interface IBehaviourQueueItem<out T>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you would want IBehaviourA associated with property A, and IBehaviourB with property B.

If the above is right, could you try something like:

```
BehaviourQueueItem<T> AddBehaviour() where T : IBehaviour;
```

instead of

```
BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour> AddBehaviour<T>() where T : IBehaviour;
```

By this we can determine the object type at BehaviourQueueItem class level itself.

Comment: If I do this, I cannot choose what type of IBehaviour I want to add and that would force me to make the type of queue to IBehaviourA Or B.